# Cross compiling: link to libx11

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, runtime-error, cross-compiling, x11

I am cross compiling an application that uses an OpenGL based library on a x86_64 host for an ARM system.

This OpenGL based library is linked to libx11. The build step is successful.

But at runtime I get the following error:

```
symbol lookup error: /home/ex/temp/lib64/libOpenglRendx.so: undefined symbol: XOpenDisplay
```

When building and running for x86_64, this works properly.

My guess is that somehow it fails to dynamically load the x11 library when running on the ARM platform.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: It's not a dynamic linking problem. You must have the library installed.

Comment: @datenwolf: you mean I must have the ARM libx11 installed on the build machine, or on the ARM machine? I did 'sudo apt-get install libx11-dev' on both of them before building it.

Comment: I also manually installed libOpenglRendx.so, same result.

Comment: On the build machine you must install the library for the target platform. `apt-get install libx11-dev` will install the development files for the architecture of your build machine, not the library for the target platform! You'll have to add the ARM repositories to your apt sources and do a multilib install. Also when compiling and linking the program you'll have to use the proper target tuple for compilers and linker, i.e. something along the lines `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead of just `gcc` and the likes.

Comment: The compiling works fine, otherwise it the executable wouldn't start at all. At this moment it's not at all clear to me how the linker decides which library (between the host and the target) to link to.

Comment: Well, at compilation time you're not yet dealing with the *actual* library. You just use the header, which is a mere "table of contents" so to speak. And the linker decides where to pull the library by looking at the used platform tuple.

Comment: So if the target library is not installed on the host computer, why doesn't the linking fail in the first place?

Comment: Ok, I'm finally starting to understand how this should work. Right now on the host machine I only have libX11.so (libc6,x86-64) installed, I would also need the arm64 (or aarch64?) installed. But I haven't managed to install it yet. There are unmet dependencies so apt-get complains about it.